# JSF Jquery autocomplete setting ID to backing bean not working

Tags: jsf-2, jquery-autocomplete

Jquery autocomplete in jsf2.0 in xhtml working fine, but when I am trying to set value to backing bean in select function it is not getting set, i have used

```
<div class="ui-widget" style="font-size: 0.9em; padding-left: 0.3em;"  >
                        <label for="organizatiosSelectAuto">Representative Organization: </label>
                        <h:inputText id="organizationSelectAuto"/>
                    </div>
<h:inputText id="orgIDHidden" value="#{letterMBean.orgID}" style="" immediate="true"    onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{letterMBean.orgChanged(this)}"/>

$(function() {
        var availableTags = #{jqueryClientList.arrayObj} ;
        $( '#organizationSelectAuto' ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {    
             alert("id"+ui.item.id);
              document.getElementById('housefrm:orgIDHidden').value = ui.item.id;
              alert("input Text vlaue"+document.getElementById('housefrm:orgIDHidden').value);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It started working as somehow i have to submit form in jquery function after select

    <h:commandButton id="populateOrgId" action="#{letterMBean.orgChanged}" style="display: none" >
                                </h:commandButton>     
    document.getElementById('housefrm:populateOrgId').click();

Answer (score 0):

It started working as somehow i have to submit form in jquery function after select

```
<h:commandButton id="populateOrgId" action="#{letterMBean.orgChanged}" style="display: none" >     </h:commandButton> document.getElementById('housefrm:populateOrgId').click();
```